# Php Фатальная ошибка.(mb_substr)

Tags: php

возникает ошибка при использовании функции mb_substr()
Fatal error: Uncaught Error: Call to undefined function subsrt() in C:\xampp\htdocs\mylocalweb.loc\index.php:4 Stack trace: #0 {main} thrown in C:\xampp\htdocs\mylocalweb.loc\index.php on line 4

на сервере включена mbstring

реально сидел и думал, что не так, спасибо за ответ))

Comment: `subsrt()`  местами буквы поменяйте